# Signal-TLS-Proxy Kubernetes Deployment not working

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I've been trying to deploy the Signal-TLS-Proxy ([GitHub](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-TLS-Proxy)) in my Kubernetes cluster for a few days now with no success.

It doesn't work when I try and configure the proxy in the app, nor when I try via curl.

Bellow is the yaml definitions I've managed to cobble together.

**Configmap**

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  auto;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }

    stream {
        map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
            chat.signal.org                         signal-service;
            ud-chat.signal.org                      signal-service;
            storage.signal.org                      storage-service;
            cdn.signal.org                          signal-cdn;
            cdn2.signal.org                         signal-cdn2;
            cdsi.signal.org                         cdsi;
            contentproxy.signal.org                 content-proxy;
            uptime.signal.org                       uptime;
            api.backup.signal.org                   backup;
            sfu.voip.signal.org                     sfu;
            svr2.signal.org                         svr2;
            updates.signal.org                      updates;
            updates2.signal.org                     updates2;
            default                                 deny;
        }

        upstream signal-service {
            server chat.signal.org:443;
        }

        upstream storage-service {
            server storage.signal.org:443;
        }

        upstream signal-cdn {
            server cdn.signal.org:443;
        }

        upstream signal-cdn2 {
            server cdn2.signal.org:443;
        }

        upstream cdsi {
            server cdsi.signal.org:443;
        }

        upstream content-proxy {
            server contentproxy.signal.org:443;
        }

        upstream backup {
            server api.backup.signal.org:443;
        }

        upstream sfu {
            server sfu.voip.signal.org:443;
        }

        upstream svr2 {
            server svr2.signal.org:443;
        }

        upstream updates {
            server updates.signal.org:443;
        }

        upstream updates2 {
            server updates2.signal.org:443;
        }

        upstream deny {
            server 127.0.0.1:9;
        }

        server {
            listen                4433;
            proxy_pass            $name;
            ssl_preread           on;
            error_log             /dev/null;
            access_log            off;
        }
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: signal-proxy-config
  namespace: default
```

**Deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: signal-proxy
  namespace: default
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          name: config-volume
          subPath: nginx.conf
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: signal-proxy-config
        name: config-volume
```

**Service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: signal-proxy-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - port: 4433
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

**Ingress**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: signal-proxy-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: s.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: signal-proxy-service
            port:
              number: 4433
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - s.example.com
    secretName: s-example-tls
```

As mentioned before, I am unable configure the proxy in the Signal app or test it via curl.

Bellow is my output when testing with curl

```
~$ curl -x https://s.example.com https://chat.signal.org -vv
*   Trying x.x.x.x:443...
* Connected to s.example.com (x.x.x.x) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* Proxy certificate:
*  subject: CN=s.example.com
*  start date: Sep 29 07:17:20 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 28 07:17:19 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "s.example.com" matched cert's "s.example.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* CONNECT tunnel: HTTP/1.1 negotiated
* allocate connect buffer
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to chat.signal.org:443
> CONNECT chat.signal.org:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: chat.signal.org:443
> User-Agent: curl/8.3.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Sun, 01 Oct 2023 22:26:45 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 150
< Connection: close
<
* CONNECT tunnel failed, response 400
* Closing connection
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
curl: (56) CONNECT tunnel failed, response 400
```